# Why is gcc 7.3 accepting 'this' in a static definition?

Tags: c++, gcc, static, instance

I have this MCVE:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

class VectorInside
{
    public:
        std::vector<int>    classVector;
        auto processItems() -> void;
};

using foo = struct foo
{
    std::function<bool()>   someLambda;
};

auto VectorInside::processItems() -> void
{
    static std::vector<foo> allItems =
    {
        { [&] () -> bool { return 1 == this->classVector.size(); } }
    };
    for ( auto const & currentItem : allItems )
    {
        printf( "size() == 1: %s\n", true == currentItem.someLambda() ? "YES" : "NO" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    VectorInside test1, test2;
    test1.classVector.resize(1);

    test1.processItems();
    test2.processItems();
}
```

In my eyes `gcc` shouldn't compile this code because it is clear that the `static` definition of `allItems` takes the `VectorInside` instance of the very first call and therefore each following call returns only the size of `test1` which calls as 1st `processItems()`.

---

**Result:**

```
size() == 1: YES
size() == 1: YES
```

Removing `static` gives the correct result because each call of `processItems()` generates a *fresh* content of `allItems`.

```
size() == 1: YES
size() == 1: NO
```

For me it was clear that using `static` does not return correct result but I was surprised `gcc 7.3` accepts this code.

---

**Technical data:**

The options for `gcc 7.3` to compile it:
`-O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -pedantic-errors`

---

**My question:**

Is this `C++17` conform? Code like this can never be correct.

Comment: `auto processItems() -> void;` why are you using that instead of `void processItems();`? The return type is not dependant on anything that needs to be auto-deduced

Comment: The `static` applies only to the `allItems` variable itself.  The `this` is valid inside the lambda that is being assigned to `allItems`.  It just happens that only 1 lambda is created due to static initialization

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but `this` is clear _inside_ the context of the `static allItems` variable...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. You have a static variable that is initialized the first time it is used. It just happens to be initialized with a lambda that accesses the first `VectorInside` object that called `processItems()`. The lambda will keep accessing that object every time it is called. So why do you expect this code NOT to compile? Do you expect the compiler to be smart enough to detect a capturing lambda being assigned to a static variable and reject the code?

Comment: @RemyLebeau In C++ a static variable inside a function has a _has-been-created-flag_. This means when the function is called the 1st time this flag is checked and when it is `false` then the static variable is _filled_ and the flag is set. So it is clear that a static variable depending on `this` never can have correct value when the function is called from other instance.

Comment: I know how a static local variable works. I don't see why this should make the compiler reject the code. It is valid code, it just doesn't have the semantics you are expecting. I expect a lambda that captures `this` and is assigned to a static variable would fall into "undefined behavior" territory when it uses `this` later on, that's all.

Comment: @AlBundy Don't make assumptions on how static is implemented.

Comment: By your logic I should not be able to use `static MyClass x(this);` Which is perfectly valid. The first time `processItems()` it is initialized with a given context. After that it is not re-initialized so the state it captured does not change.

Comment: `using foo = struct foo` this is hilarious, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyword `static` has three or four entirely different meanings!

1. On a namespace member declaration, the name has internal linkage (does not name the same thing as anything found in a different translation unit).
2. On a class member declaration, the member "belongs to" the class as a whole, not each object of the class type.

   - For a data class member, exactly one object exists, and uses of the member name all refer to the same object, instead of having a different member subobject in each class object.
   - For a class member function, the function can be called without an object of the class type, and the `this` keyword is not valid in its definition.
3. On an object definition within a function, exactly one object exists used by all calls to that function (sequential or recursive), instead of having a separate object for each call to the function.  The object's initializer is evaluated and the object is initialized only the first time the statement is reached.  If it has a class type, the destructor is called when `exit` is called or `main` returns, in the reverse order of creation along with other function-`static` objects, namespace member objects, and static class member objects.

(Meaning 1 was mostly taken from the C language.  Meaning 3 was also from the C language, with the part about class destructors added.  Meaning 2 is not found in C at all.)

In your code, `processItems` is NOT a `static` class member, so "`this`" is valid inside it.  `allItems` is declared as `static`, but it is defined by a function statement, and is not a class member at all, so the third meaning above applies, and the third meaning has no effect on the semantics of the `this` keyword.  Your code does exactly as described for the third meaning: the initializer, which involves capturing a `this` pointer in a lambda, is evaluated only the very first time.

The third meaning doesn't even need to involve a class at all:

```
// Returns a different sequential value on each call (until overflow)
unsigned int nextValue() {
    static unsigned int counter = 0;
    return counter++;
}
```

Comment: I understand. As Martin York stated using `this` can be perfectly valid. Your last paragraph lights me up. Thx.

Comment: Just a minor tip: make processItems static and I will suicide if it compiles with a this within.